# Yii active record for mysql and ms sql

Tags: php, sql-server, yii

I am using active record of yii framework. I started my project using mysql. Now i wanted to run on ms sql 2008. I had connected the ms sql 2008 with my project.
Some of the page loading properly.But I am facing some issue like column name  as key words to both sql server like "group,user".

```
<?php

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select=array('`group`','type');//for mysql
$criteria->select=array('[group]','type');//for ms sql

?>
```

so i wanted to write one select criteria which will run both the server.
Thank you for reply.

Comment: Interesting question.. I appreciate you. !

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/192/config-use-ms-sql-server-2005-2008/

Comment: I already referred this link for connection. in this link there is no solution for my issue.

Comment: You can acheive that by installing an MSSQL Driver right?? Are u finding it hard?

Comment: My project is connected with ms sql perfectly. some of the pages are working properly. my issue to select a column which is key word to ms sql so i have to put square bracket([]) to get column record. which i don't wanted because in mysql then i have to put tilde(`) sign.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use quoteColumnName for this purpose in Yii 1.1:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#quoteColumnName-detail

So untested example code would be something like:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$colGroup = $this->dbConnection->quoteColumnName('group');
$criteria->select=array($colGroup,'type');
```

Might something like this work for you?